# JW player unable to play audio file from http handler

Tags: jwplayer

I wrote a c# handler which returns back an Audio file. JW player is unable to play it but it's playable by other player like "mp3_maxi player".

here is Handler url:

```
http://176.28.53.232/Handler.ashx?id=1
```

And here is the address of Demo

```
http://176.28.53.232/default.aspx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provider should be sound,
provider:"sound"